# Self signed Certificate Warning for Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

After booting, on the first launch of Chrome browser, every time I see a pair of self signed root certificate warnings by Kaspersky Antivirus. It happens only with Chrome, and not with Firefox or IE.

I been seeing this for past few days, and when I view certificate, it's a 4 set, alphanumerical string separated by dashes total of 32 characters. The certificate always has 2 days validity, and everyday it updates validity. For instance today it's 2/18-2/20, yesterday it was 2/17-2/19

**25a029c5-c3f7-32b8-2caa-1667e6fa9b13**

**Kaspersky Warning about first Certificate**

[image: Kaspersky Warning about first Certificate]

**Certificate Properites**

[image: Certificate Validity]

**Kaspersky Warning about second Certificate**
[image: Kaspersky Warning about second Certificate]

I initially thought it's related to an add-on, but been seeing this even after disabling extensions on Chrome. The properties did not reveal much about the certificate itself, the "issued to" and "issued by" are same.

I am curious about this, and hoping if someone can tell me about this certificate. I'm suspicious that my Chrome is infected by Adware/Spyware. I'm going to try and reinstall Chrome to see if problem persists.

**Update 1**: I tried reinstall, delete Chrome folder completely, but not one them got rid of Certificate warning. Not sure but this may not be related/limited to Chrome.

Comment: Are the certificates installed in the certificate store?

Comment: No I couldn't find these two in the store.

Comment: You don’t specify any information in the website your attempting to visit.  Legitimate Root certificates are valid for more than 2 days.

Comment: @bobby789 Anecdotally, at one point I had a piece of software (a video streaming server) that was operating locally on port 80 handing out invalid certificates for a web site hosted on the same server. Not saying this has anything directly to do with what you are experiencing, but you may wish to investigate any programs running on your PC that might be serving these.

Comment: @Ramhound The certificate warning appears as soon as I open the browser. I did a wireshark capture, but found nothing suspicious in the external IP address that my system communicated with. I'm going to re-do the Wireshark capture to identify if the system/chrome is reaching out to a specific IP/domain, when the certificate warning appears. However it's very possible that Kapersky warning is not real-time.

Comment: If you have Kaspersky configured to scan HTTPS traffic, Kaspersky might be complaining, about it's own root certicate.

Comment: @Ramhound yes that's possible but it happens only with Chrome and not with other browsers. And the certificate does not give out much details about it's identity.

Comment: @bobby789 - Does that mean you do indeed have Kaspersky configured to scan your https traffic?  If that is the case, disable the functionality, and see if the behavior goes away.

Comment: @Ramhound When I disabled Kaspersky SSL inspection, I no longer saw the warning. But this could also be because Kaspersky is no longer concerned about SSL traffic inspection altogether irrespective of certificate( it's own or malicious), and stops warning me. It's interesting in the sense that I haven't changed my Kaspersky configuration in last 2 years, and the certificate warning started appearing all of a sudden a week ago, and like I mentioned it only happens with Chrome and not with other browsers. I'll try to capture traffic with Fiddler and report back if I find anything interesting.

Comment: Ramhound and @Anaksunaman  thank you both for your suggestions so far.

Comment: I don’t use security products that break HTTPS traffic by using a fake certificate so it can scan the traffic.  So I suspect the product simply supports Chrome and since it was enabled at some point Chrome was still detecting it.  If a certificate was indeed presented with that information Chrome would complain unless of course, you tell the browser by enabling SSL traffic inspection, you don’t otherwise care :$

Comment: As a followup, based on some (apparently now-deleted) forum posts, this issue may have been a bug in Kaspersky itself.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I feel the same. I reached out to Kaspersky for confirmation, awaiting response.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Kaspersky, who confirmed that this is a known issue caused by devices like Chromecast on the network.

They offered a temporary fix, however before I could implement the fix, I stopped seeing the certificate warning, so I'm guessing Kaspersky fixed it.

For anyone interested in knowing the Kaspersky's workaround, here it is

#

If using Chromecast or other Google Devices, please follow this guide:

1. Reproduce the issue and keep our product notification open. (required for step 4)
2. Open main Kaspersky window - More tools - My network - Network monitor;
3. Sort the table by Port (or type in Chrome in the search field);
4. Find the port 8009 used by Google Chrome ​and note down the IP address used by it (like 192.168.0.x).
5. Afterwards open Kaspersky settings (gear icon at the bottom left) - protection - application control - manage applications;
6. In the search field type "chrome";
7. Double click the Google Chrome application and go to "Exclusions"
8. Tick the "Do not scan all traffic" and select "Do not scan encrypted traffic";
9. Tick on "Only for specified IP addresses" - enter the IP address from step 4.
10. Tick on "Only for specified ports" - 8009
11. Click Save.